# How to stop flicker issue (while scrolling) in IE when position set to absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with a header fixed at the top of my table. I used `position:absolute` and updated the `top` value using `scrollTop` when scroll is done. I didnt use `position:fixed` for some reason.

Now, the concept is working fine perfect in chrome but i checked in IE, there is a flicker causing in the header when scroll is made.

This is the code.

```
  $("#container").scroll(function() {
     $(".header").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": $(this).scrollTop()
     });
  });
```

I searched for the solution but the result is kept the position fixed or use a plugin. But i dont want to use plugins because mine is working good in chrome.

I just want to fix the flicker problem in IE. I dont know how to fix it. Guys, help me with this.

Thanks :) ( Note: I dont want to use position fixed )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast, i figured it out. There is a workaround for this flicker problem. Disabling `Smooth Scrolling` will fix this problem.

You can find this option under `Internet Options -> Advanced(Tab) -> Browsing -> Show smooth scrolling`

Comment: so it's only a client fix, not something you can handle code-wise, so... not that useful. right?

Comment: Yes....but in my case, it is the only fix because, i cant use position:fixed in my table due to some reason. But, we can fix it by adding position:fixed